# How can I write to a file using a java script on my server?

Tags: java, php, apache

I have some uploaded java programs that I need to run, and view the source code.  Right now, I have a php script which collects the uploaded java files, compiles them, and then tries to run them.  Currently, using exec/system, I can compile the *.java files into *.class files.  However, when I have try "java programName", I get an error saying that permission is denied to the output file.

The directories are owned by www-data, which uploaded the files, and correctly compiles the programs.  When I run the script from command line, everything works fine, but when I go to a web brwser I get the following error: "Error: file.out Permission Denied".  This error does not show up in the apache error log.

Comment: Post the output of `ls -al file.out`.

Comment: The file doesn't exist.  The java program is supposed to create it.

Comment: Did you try giving the output directory write permission? `chmod 777 /var/www/path/to/output/`

Comment: Tried, get the same error.

Comment: Are you specifying an absolute path to the output file? It might be trying to create it completely elsewhere, like in `/usr/local/bin` or wherever `java` is located, or in the home directory (which `www-data` usually doesn't have).

Comment: I don't think so, because when I run the php from the server command line it puts file.out in the correct location.